# Low-Level Tensorflow, dataset.as_numpy_iterator() returns dicts instead of numpy arrays

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, mnist, low-level

When I try to import and batch the dataset using the method with [`tf.data.Dataset.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch)
and use the dataset.as_numpy_iterator(), the iterated objects are dicts, even though I should get multiple numpy arrays.

```
dataset = tfds.load('mnist', split='train')
dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=False)
for i in dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
    print(type(i))  # prints <class 'dict'>
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as_supervised = True

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
dataset = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', as_supervised=True)
dataset.batch(10, drop_remainder=False)
for image, label in tfds.as_numpy(dataset):
    print(type(image), type(label), label)
```

According to TensorFlow documentation if as_supervised is False you will get dictionary values.
Check Docs [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load)